# Change td width to percentage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my issue for programming at work I have to use a program that I won't name, no big deal there.  But I need to create some responsive design for a progress bar and am having some issues changing the widths to percentages using js. It seems to be an easy issue, I know what I need to do if the td elements where labeled with ids instead of just classes.  I can't get getElementsByClassName to work for me but have no issue if I can manipulate the html and insert ids and use getElementsById.  So basically my question is what am I doing wrong in the coding of my js that its not performing properly or is there another option I am missing.

Here is the js fiddle that I can't get to work: http://jsfiddle.net/xHfm7/
`document.getElementsByClassName("progLf").width = document.getElementsByClassName("progLf").width + "%";`

Here is the fiddle showing it working with Id grab: http://jsfiddle.net/5uHZ9/

`document.getElementById("progLf").width =
document.getElementById("progLf").width + "%";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the name of the function `getElementsByClassName`.  Note it is "Elements", plural.  It returns a collection of elements, even if there is only one match.  Therefore you have to select one of them to operate on using the function `item()`.

Assuming you want the first match, try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("progLf").item(0).width = blah
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you @BigBadaboom.  Figured it was something simple I was missing.  If anyone needs to see it in action here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xHfm7/1/